# Maven Android project does not work with Java 8

Tags: java, android, maven

Whenever I try to use Java 8 language-features I get the following exception:

```
Error:Android Dex: [AndroidTest] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Android Dex: [AndroidTest] java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
```

I'm using the Android Maven plugin with Android 22 and a Nexus S 22 emulator in IntelliJ IDEA. Language and compiler level is set to 1.8. This works fine until I use a Java 8 feature, then I get the exception when deploying.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.me</groupId>
<artifactId>AndroidTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>AndroidTest</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <platform.version> 4.1.1.4
        </platform.version>
    <android.plugin.version>3.6.0</android.plugin.version>
    <sdk-version>22</sdk-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>${sdk-version}</platform>
                </sdk>
                                </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.me"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="22"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatelty, Current version of dex is not working with Java 8. You cannot use java8-related features when compiling for the android platform.

You can configure the maven-compiler plugin in order to enforce java version :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```