# Android Studio cannot run project - Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have added a own created lib (coded in Intellij Idea 14) to my existing android studio project, but now I cannot build an run it.

I used Java version 8 for both!

Adding this:

```
android {
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    ...
}
```

Did not solve my problem! Also restarting Android Studio or cleaning the cash has no effect.

So what can I try next?

The full error message:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    ... 12 more
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.614 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397160/maven-android-project-does-not-work-with-java-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved my problem:**

The android studio code was correct, but in the Idea lib project java **sdk 1.8** was set. After changing this to 1.7 everything works like expected.

Thx rafael for your hint!